# How to determine the default browser of the system without entering registry in programmatic way?

Tags: c#

I am looking for the solution to determine the default browser of my Win10 without entering registry.

For now I know it only using registry.

For example, is there an option to access Settings -> Apps -> Default apps? Or any `wmic` command to know it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why do you want to avoid reading the registry?

Comment: Just stupid quirk of my team lead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Process.Start`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=net-5.0#system-diagnostics-process-start(system-string)) accepts the name of a document and will open the default application for that document. You can then inspect the name of the process.

```
var process = Process.Start("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
Console.WriteLine("Your default browser is " + process.ProcessName);
```

Comment: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'The system cannot find the file specified.' 
exception was thrown.

Comment: The exact same code works fine for me. Perhaps your system lacks a default browser to begin with. When you run this code, does a browser open for you?

Comment: No, it does not, but I checked it, my default browser is Chrome.

I use System.Diagnostics for Process.Start, maybe the problem is here?

Comment: Ok, I got it. Does not work with .NET Core.

Answer (score 0):

On .NET Core it works in this way:

```
myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "http://www.stackoverflow.com";
myProcess.Start();
Console.WriteLine("Your default browser is " + myProcess.ProcessName);
```